# Issue Fetching Product Data from Strapi in Next.js

Tags: fetch-api, strapi, next.js13

I have encountered an issue while attempting to retrieve product data from Strapi in Next.js. Everything proceeds smoothly until I attempt to fetch baseTitle, Description, or Color. At this point, an error message is displayed.

[Screenshot of error message in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Wwp.png)

I am fetching data using async function like this:

```
export default async function Product({ params }: {params: {id: number}}) {
  try{
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL}/products/${params.id}?populate=*`);
  if(!res.ok){
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${res.status}`);
    }
    const data = await res.json();
```

I am using Insomnia to test the API and fetch the data, and everything appears to be working fine there.

[Screenshot of data in Insomnia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STqBb.png)

In Strapi, I have created a *Base* as a collection-type and established a one-to-one relation with products. I initially considered the possibility of it sending an array, but in Insomnia, it is displayed in a normal data format. Therefore, I am unsure where the issue lies.

[Screenshot of Strapi panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKjHB.png)

I tried different methods of fetching data in Next.js, for example in another array, but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can using SWR library in NextJS 13. using fetch api *npm install swr*
Example

```html
//app/api/products/route.ts
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function GET() {
  const res = await fetch(process.env.PATH_URL_BACKEND+'/api/products', {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
  const result = await res.json()
  return NextResponse.json({ result })
}
 
 
 //in page component , you can using swr the following the below code
 'use client'
import Link from "next/link";
import useSWR from "swr";
const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
export default function Menu() {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR<any>(
    `/api/products`,
    fetcher
  );
 
  if (error) return <div>Failed to load</div>;
  if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
  if (!data) return null;
  return (
    <div>
      show data here
    </div>
  )
  }
```

If you using useEffetch in Nextjs 13, you setting config it

```html
const [products, setProducts] =  useState();
useEffetch(()=>{
  if(data){
    setProducts(data)
  }

},[data, isLoading]);
```

You can see it in article after
[Create A Example Handling Data Fetching With SWR In NextJS](https://hoanguyenit.com/create-a-example-handling-data-fetching-with-swr-in-nextjs.html)

[Building A Simple CRUD API With Next.Js 13](https://hoanguyenit.com/building-a-simple-crud-api-with-nextjs-13.html)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Next JS are you using? Just wondering.  If you are not getting any errors in insomnia, the issue is within your next js app.

If you put console log here what do you get?

```
export default async function Product({ params }: {params: {id: number}}) {
  try{
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_URL}/products/${params.id}?populate=*`);
  if(!res.ok){
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${res.status}`);
    }
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data). // what do you get here ???
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I didn't change much. For some reason, when I organized my code a bit and created constants for each data type, the code started working after restarting the next and strapi applications. Thank you very much to everyone for their willingness to help. Below, I have attached pictures of the working code.

[VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ5aR.png)
[Insomnia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz6PP.jpg)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.